# Automated Setup of Kibana and Elasticsearch with Filebeat Module in Elastic Cloud for Kubernetes (ECK)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat

I'm trying out the K8s Operator (a.k.a. ECK) and so far, so good.

However, I'm wondering what the right pattern is for, say, configuring Kibana and Elasticsearch with the Apache module.

I know I can do it ad hoc with:

```
filebeat setup --modules apache2 --strict.perms=false \
  --dashboards --pipelines --template \
  -E setup.kibana.host="${KIBANA_URL}"
```

But what's the automated way to do it? I see some docs for the [Kibana dashboard portion of it](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-beat-configuration.html#k8s-beat-set-up-kibana-dashboards) but what about the rest (pipelines, etc.)?

Note: At some point, I may end up actually running a beat for the K8s cluster, but I'm not at that stage yet. At the moment, I just want to set Elasticsearch/Kibana up with the Apache module additions so that external Apache services' Filebeats can get ingested/displayed properly.

FYI, I'm on version 6.8 of the Elastic stack for now.

Answer (score 0):

you can try auto-discovery using label based approach.

```
config:
filebeat.autodiscover:
 providers:
  - type: kubernetes
    hints.default_config.enabled: "false"
    templates:
      - condition.contains:
        kubernetes.labels.app: "apache"
    config:
    - module: apache
      access:
        enabled: true
        var.paths: ["/path/to/log/apache/access.log*"]
      error:
        enabled: true
        var.paths: ["/path/to/log/apache/error.log*"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It looks like this is actually configuring a Filebeat, versus _just_ prepping Kibana and Elasticsearch for Filebeats. The services being logged are not on K8s yet, so I think this answer isn't quite what I want (yet).
Please let me know if I've misunderstood, though.